# Passing arrays from AJAX to HTML to PHP - Is this Possible?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, codeigniter, return-value

**I have an AJAX call returning an array to a PHP-HTML page.**

---

Here are some blocks of codes:

**Javascript:**

**"Note: get_data.php returns an HTML string, and I want to store it in an array."**

```
var param_array = new Array();
$.post('get_data.php', { id: id }, function(data))
{
    param_array.push(data);
    $('#hidden_input').val(param_array);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action='my_function' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' id='hidden_input' name='array_from_ajax'>
    <input type='submit' name='btn_submit'>
</form>
```

**PHP - CodeIgniter:**

```
my_function()
{
    $param_array = $this->input->post('array_from_ajax');
    print_r($param_array); // Will this work? will $param_array contain the value?
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to return an array value and insert it into the HTML page?
2. Is a JavaScript array the same as a PHP array?
3. In the end, will my `$param_array` in PHP contain the value passed from the AJAX call?

Comment: can't you just do a test and give us the errors, if any?

Comment: Actually the actual source is kinda 'LOTS OF LINES' I just summarized it, so I kinda like to ask if this algorithm I thought would work before I could do the major changes. :)

Comment: ah ok. I would stick with the JSON-encode answer, that's the normal way to handle such a communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript and PHP can only communicate over HTTP and only via strings (unless you could SOAP I guess, if that's even possible).  That is to say there is no compatibility in data structures between them, so a JavaScript array <> a PHP array.  Similarly, you can't set the input value to a JavaScript array.

The best way to handle this would probably be to JSON-encode the array before setting it to the value of the input.  PHP can easily decode the JSON into data structures it can use.

Comment: so is it now possible to have it like this afterwards? like `json_encode(data); $('#hidden_input').val(json_encode);` ? will php now get the array? Sorry, Im not familiar with JSON :)

Comment: @PawCabelin use `$("#hidden_input").val(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: @ExplosionPills thanks!, I'll just search some tutorials about JSON.stringify. thanks for your help.